# Blackberry 6&7 .cod file is not connected to the server

Tags: blackberry, ibm-mobilefirst, blackberry-webworks

In work-light 7.0 .At the time of building Blackberry 6&7 Environment is not asking any web-works_home environment variable but its build successfully.By using command bbwp.exe archive-folder ,I get the .cod file. I manually created the archive-folder.App is launching successfully. ,but it is not connected to the server.I checked one line in config.xml is  .I changed to My work-light server host also.But It fails to connecting to the server.I am using web-works sdk for BB6&7 BlackBerryWebWorksSDK2.3.1.5.

[manually created archive folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTCj5.png)

Answer (score 0):

I already replied to your previous question, on the very same subject.
I don't know why you keep thinking there should even be webworks_home environment variable. I linked you to the instructions and where they clearly **do not** require any such variable: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/setting-up-your-development-environment/setting-blackberry-6-7-development-environment/

There are also instructions on how to preview your application and run it on a device or simulator: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/hello-world/previewing-application-blackberry-6-7/

Note that the BlackBerry 6/7 environment is **deprecated** and will be removed in a future release.

Comment: But my .cod generated file is not hiting to the server when i launch in simulator.where to see server host in blackberry 6&7.In config.xml is not there